# how to solve expando strange behaviour to fill mvc3 webgrid?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller

I tries to fill webgrid using one [answered 
question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11306458/how-to-bind-json-dynamic-model-in-asp-net-mvc-3) and [an article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg650669.aspx), But I can not my all rows repeat same as value. All rows values are the same as others. I have been debugging to solve this strange problem. But I can not:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<string> Columns { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<dynamic> Values { get; set; }
    public bool HasNext { get; set; }
    public bool HasPrevious { get; set; }
}

public class JobController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index(int? page)
    {
        ViewData["Customers"] = new SelectList(CustomerOperation.GetCustomers().Items, "Id", "Name", null);
        ViewData["Jobs"] = new SelectList(JobOperation.GetCustomersAssemblyList().Items, "scheduleId", "name", null);
        const int pageSize = 10;
        ViewBag.CurrentPage = (page ?? 0);
        if (Session["CustomerId"]!=null && Session["ScheduleId"]!=null)
        {
            int customerId = ConvertUtil.ToInt(Session["CustomerId"]);
            int scheduleId = ConvertUtil.ToInt(Session["ScheduleId"]);
            var model = GetPagedVals((page ?? 0) * pageSize, pageSize, customerId, scheduleId);
            ViewBag.HasPrevious = model.HasPrevious;
            ViewBag.HasMore = model.HasNext;

            return View(model);
        }
        else
            return View();
    }
 public MyViewModel GetPagedVals(int skip, int take, int Id, int scheduleId)
   {
       Session["CustomerId"] = Id;
       Session["ScheduleId"] = scheduleId;
       DataTable dt = JobOperation.GetJobsBySchedulerIdAndCustomerId(scheduleId, Id);
       List<dynamic> dataList = new List<dynamic>();
       dynamic expando = new ExpandoObject();
       var p = expando as IDictionary<String, object>;

       IEnumerable<string> columnNames = dt.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().Select(x => x.ColumnName);
       foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
       {
           foreach (string columnName in columnNames)
           {

               p[columnName] = ConvertUtil.ToString(dr[columnName]);

           }
           dataList.Add(expando);
        }

       var result = dataList.Skip(skip).Take(take).ToList();
       var model = new MyViewModel();
       model.Columns = columnNames;
       model.Values = result;
       model.HasNext = (skip + 10 < dataList.Count);
       model.HasPrevious = (skip > 0);
       ViewBag.HasPrevious = model.HasPrevious;
       ViewBag.HasMore = model.HasNext;

       return model;
   }
```

Result is below:

[image]

But All row is the same as anthers! Result must be below :
[image]
My sql queries working good. No problem sql. My repeated rows last row. How to solve this strange problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dynamic expando = new ExpandoObject();
```

You only ever create *one* `ExpandoObject` instance.
You add this same instance to the list once for each row, overwriting the properties each time.

You need to create a `new` instance for each row.